# syntax mistakes in java code in android

Tags: java, android

I am very new to coding ,started learning android .
I am facing some minor syntax errors in java code(my activity.java)
.please help me in this. 
Program is to add the two numbers and display the result

```
package com.example.apple.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText firstNumber;
    EditText secondNumber;
    TextView addResult;
    Button btnAdd;

    double num1,num2,sum;

    firstNumber = findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
    secondNumber = findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
    addResult = findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
    btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

}

 btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View v) {
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
    sum = num1 + num2;
    addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum));
    }
    });
```

Comment: You're at least going to have to tell us what the errors are.

Comment: `btnAdd.setOnClickListener ...` should be in a method, probably in the `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2):

Like @NickL mentioned, your click event should be in a method. You can place it directly in your `onCreate` like this:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
        //Do what you want with the click here
        } 
    });

}
```

Or you can call your method in `onCreate` like this:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myCoolButtonMethod();

}

private void myCoolButtonMethod(){

    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
        //Do what you want with the click here
        } 
    });

}
```

You also declared your methods incorrectly, in your case it will look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    EditText firstNumber; 
    EditText secondNumber; 
    TextView addResult; 
    Button btnAdd; 
    double num1,num2,sum;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        firstNumber = findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1); 
        secondNumber = findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2); 
        addResult = findViewById(R.id.txtResult); 
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        myCoolButtonMethod();

    }

    private void myCoolButtonMethod(){
    Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString()); 
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString()); 
            sum = num1 + num2;
            addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum)); 
        } 
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:-
Put onClick method in onCreate.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText firstNumber;
    EditText secondNumber;
    TextView addResult;
    Button btnAdd;

    double num1,num2,sum;

    firstNumber = findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
    secondNumber = findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
    addResult = findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
    btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
            sum = num1 + num2;
            addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum));
        }
    });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have to change views declaration to

```
secondNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.action_save);
    addResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_save);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_save);
```

then change the double variable to be final.
and you have to put

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

inside

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

block method.

this is the full code :

```
package com.example.apple.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.android.pets.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        EditText firstNumber;
        EditText secondNumber;
        final TextView addResult;
        Button btnAdd;

        final double num1, num2, sum;

        firstNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.action_save);
        secondNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.action_save);
        addResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_save);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_save);


        num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
        sum = num1 + num2;

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect - `first of all, you have to change views declaration to`